# Unique Structure in base for powers $1,2$ and $3$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, analytic-number-theory

Let's $1<a\in\mathbb{N}$

And $$A^{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{a}i^{k}$$

Here $t $ is a number from any base $q$ can be converted in base $b$ written as

$$(t)_{q}=(b_{r} b_{r-1} ... b_{2} b_{1})_{b}$$

Now function $\Lambda$ is define as

$$\Lambda (t)=\sum_{j=1}^{r} b_{j}$$

> > **Question**

> > Prove this

> > Here $b=a+1$
> > and $$B^{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{b}i^{k}$$

> > If $$a|A^{k}$$
> > Then
> > $$\Lambda(B^{k})=b$$

> > For every $a$ and $k=1,2and3$

**Note**
$a>1$ and I observed it only ture for $k=1,2$ and $3$

I think,may be it's difficult and important question in mathematics. And it's my strong observation.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Prove statement in Question blog

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346971/unique-structure-in-base-for-power-1-2-and-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll restate the problem, changing the notation for convenience . . .

**Problem:**

For positive integers $n,k$, let
$$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k$$
and for positive integers $m,b$, with $b>1$, let $D(m,b)$ be the sum of the base-$b$ digits of $m$.

Show that if $k\in\{1,2,3\}$, and $a$ is a positive integer such that $a{\,|\,}S(a,k)$, then $D(S(b,k),b)=b$, where $b=a+1$.

**Proof:**

Consider cases, based on the value of $k$ . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;k=1$.

Thus, suppose $a$ is a positive integer such that $a{\,|\,}S(a,1)$, and let $b=a+1$.

Identically, we have
$$
S(n,1)
=
\sum_{i=1}^n i
=
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
so
\begin{align*}
&a{\,|\,}S(a,1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a{\;|}\left(\frac{a(a+1)}{2}\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2{\;|\,}(a+1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2{\,|\,}b\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, since
\begin{align*}
S(b,1)&=\frac{b(b+1)}{2}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{b}{2}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^1 + \left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^0
\end{align*}
it follows that 
$$
D(S(b,1),b)
=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)+\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)
=
b
$$
so case $(1)$ is done.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;k=2$.

Thus, suppose $a$ is a positive integer such that $a{\,|\,}S(a,2)$, and let $b=a+1$.

Identically, we have
$$
S(n,2)
=
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
=
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&a{\,|\,}S(a,2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a{\;|}\left(
\frac{a(a+1)(2a+1)}{6}
\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&6{\;|}\left((a+1)(2a+1)\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&6{\;|}\left(b(2b-1)\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&6{\,|\,}b\;\;\text{or}\;\;\Bigl(2{\,|\,}b\;\;\text{and}\;\;3{\;|\,}(2b-1)\Bigr)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
If $6{\,|\,}b$, then
\begin{align*}
S(b,2)&=\frac{b(b+1)(2b+1)}{6}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^3}{3}+\frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{b}{6}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{3}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^2 
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^1
+ 
\left({\small{\frac{b}{6}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^0
\end{align*}
hence
$$
D(S(b,2),b)
=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{3}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{6}}}\right)
=
b
$$
If $2{\,|\,}b\;\;$and$\;\;3{\;|\,}(2b-1)$, then $b\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;3)$, so
\begin{align*}
S(b,2)&=\frac{b(b+1)(2b+1)}{6}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^3}{3}+\frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{b}{6}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b+1}{3}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^2 
+
\left({\small{\frac{b-2}{6}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^1
+ 
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^0
\end{align*}
hence
$$
D(S(b,2),b)
=
\left({\small{\frac{b+1}{3}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b-2}{6}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{6}}}\right)
=
b
$$
Thus, for all subcases of case $(2)$, we have $D(S(b,2),b)=b$, so case $(2)$ is done.

**Case $(3)$:**$\;k=3$.

Thus, suppose $a$ is a positive integer such that $a{\,|\,}S(a,3)$, and let $b=a+1$.

Identically, we have
$$
S(n,3)
=
\sum_{i=1}^n i^3
=
\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&a{\,|\,}S(a,3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a{\;|}\left(
\frac{a^2(a+1)^2}{4}
\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4{\;|}\left(a(a+1)^2\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4{\;|}\left((b-1)b^2\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2{\,|\,}b\;\;\text{or}\;\;4{\;|\,}(b-1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&b\equiv r\;(\text{mod}\;4)\;\text{where}\;r\in\{0,1,2\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
If $b\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;4)$, then
\begin{align*}
S(b,3)&=\frac{b^2(b+1)^2}{4}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^4}{4}+\frac{b^3}{2}+\frac{b^2}{4}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{4}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^3 
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^2
+ 
\left({\small{\frac{b}{4}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^1
+ 
(0){\cdot}\,b^0
\end{align*}
hence
$$
D(S(b,3),b)
=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{4}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{4}}}\right)
+
(0)
=
b
$$
If $b\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;4)$, then
\begin{align*}
S(b,3)&=\frac{b^2(b+1)^2}{4}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^4}{4}+\frac{b^3}{2}+\frac{b^2}{4}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b-1}{4}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^3 
+
\left({\small{\frac{3b+1}{4}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^2
+ 
(0){\cdot}\,b^1
+ 
(0){\cdot}\,b^0
\end{align*}
hence
$$
D(S(b,3),b)
=
\left({\small{\frac{b-1}{4}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{3b+1}{4}}}\right)
+
(0)
+
(0)
=
b
$$
If $b\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;4)$, then
\begin{align*}
S(b,3)&=\frac{b^2(b+1)^2}{4}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^4}{4}+\frac{b^3}{2}+\frac{b^2}{4}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b+2}{4}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^3
+ 
(0){\cdot}\,b^2
+
\left({\small{\frac{b-2}{4}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^1
+ 
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence
$$
D(S(b,3),b)
=
\left({\small{\frac{b+2}{4}}}\right)
+
(0)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b-2}{4}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)
=
b
$$
Thus, for all subcases of case $(3)$, we have $D(S(b,3),b)=b$, so case $(3)$ is done.

This completes the proof.

Comment: How to prove if $ S(b,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k} g_{i} (b)b^{i} $  then $ D(S(b,k),b) = \sum_{i=0}^{k} g_{i}(b)= b $

Comment: @Pruthviraj: That's not how $S(b,k)$ is defined.

Comment: apologies for late reply. thank you so much for your answer. can we prove problem's statement only satisfied for $k = {1,2,3}$ not for $k>3$?

Comment: @Pruthviraj: For $k > 3$, it appears to fail (i.e., there are values of $a$ for which the hypothesis is satisfied, but not the conclusion). I don't see how prove it, but I'll think about it.