# Unique pattern in addition of digits

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For positive integers $n,k$, let
$$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k$$
be the sum of the first $n$ $k$-th powers, and for positive integers $m,b$ with $b>1$, let $D(m,b)$ be the sum of the base-$b$ digits of $m$.

If $k\in\{1,2,3\}$, and $a$ is a positive integer such that $a{\,|\,}S(a,k)$, then $D(S(b,k),b)=b$, where $b=a+1$, as has been already proven [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3271109/647719).

> **Problem:**
>
> Show that for all $k > 3$, there exists $b$ s.t. $D(S(b,k),b)\ne b$.